# How Do I Create a CSV File?

Tags: excel, csv

Quick Question,

I need to create a .csv file with two columns

trainee and login

but I dont know how to make it ? Any ideas would be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the Excel file as you would normally do, but when saving it use `Save as` and save the file as a *.csv file.

Answer (score 2):

The best and easiest way is to use Excel. If you want to do this with powershell you can do it by this way :

```
$obj = new-object PSObject
$obj | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Trainee " -value "Test Trainee"
$obj | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Login" -value "Test"
$obj | export-csv sample.csv -notypeinformation
```